# Mysql performance between 2 requests

Tags: mysql

I have got 2 requests and I wonder if there is a real difference of performance between them :

```
 select count(si.entity_id)
from sales_invoice as si
         join sales_order as so on so.entity_id = si.order_id and so.grand_total > 0
where (si.grand_total <= 0 or si.grand_total is null);#return 1091

select count(si.entity_id)
from sales_order as so
         join sales_invoice si on so.entity_id = si.order_id and (si.grand_total <= 0 OR si.grand_total is null)
where so.grand_total > 0;#return 1091

select count(*) from sales_order;#return 4013933
select count(*) from sales_invoice;#return 3459174
```

Thanks you

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to use/read `EXPLAIN` plans in MySQL.  Figure out if there really is any difference in execution plan.

Comment: Well..... I believe there would be little difference unless you have  a million rows. And with MySql I don't know but lets say, Oracle or SqlServer would optimize query for you so don't matter how you write it, DB engine will do better. Although, there are hints that you can use for DB engine to follow. + a lot will depend on use of indexes, etc

Comment: Explain returns the same thing for both queries and I have 4 millions rows in each tables.

Comment: Without create tables and both explain , there is no chance to see anything. Or help.